# Chain of resposibility in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, chain-of-responsibility

Currently, I'm trying to understand the chain of responsibility, but there's some piece of code in it, that I can't understand at all. Let's start from begining.

For first, I have to create an `interface`:

```
public interface ChainLink {
    void setNextChain(ChainLink link);
    void process(Model model);
}
```

Next step is creating the pojo class:

```
public class Model {

    private int number;

    public Model(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

Now, I have to create three separated classes, for each process:

First is for negative number

```
public class NegativeNumber implements ChainLink {

     ChainLink link;
     @Override
     public void setNextChain(ChainLink link) {
         this.link = link;
     }
     @Override
     public void process(Model model) {
         if (model.getNumber() < 0){
             System.out.println("Given number is "+model.getNumber()+" and it's negative");
         }else {
             link.process(model);
         }
    }
}
```

Second one is for `number` equals to 0

```
public class ZeroNumber implements ChainLink {
     ChainLink link;
     @Override
     public void setNextChain(ChainLink link) {
         this.link = link;
     }

     @Override
     public void process(Model model) {
         if (model.getNumber() == 0){
             System.out.println("Given number is equal to 0");

         }else {
             link.process(model);
         }
     }
}
```

And the third one, for possitive numbers

```
public class PositiveNumber implements ChainLink{
     private ChainLink link;
     @Override
     public void setNextChain(ChainLink link) {
         this.link = link;
     }

     @Override
     public void process(Model model) {
         if (model.getNumber() > 0){
             System.out.println("Given number is "+model.getNumber()+" and it's positive");

         }else {
             link.process(model);
         }
     }
}
```

Now, I have to chain it up on `Main` class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         ChainLink negativeLink = new NegativeNumber();
         ChainLink zeroLink = new ZeroNumber();
         ChainLink positiveLink = new PositiveNumber();

         negativeLink.setNextChain(zeroLink);
         zeroLink.setNextChain(positiveLink);

         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

         while (true){
             int number;
             System.out.println("Enter the number");
             number = scanner.nextInt();
             negativeLink.process(new Model(number));
         }
     }
}
```

This dummy program, that I provided have to check, if the number given by the user is:
Negative, equal to 0, or positive. Im not sure, if I understand setNextChain method (which is in every process class)

```
@Override
 public void setNextChain(ChainLink link) {
     this.link = link;
 }
```

which is implemented in Main class

```
     ChainLink negativeLink = new NegativeNumber();
     ChainLink zeroLink = new ZeroNumber();
     ChainLink positiveLink = new PositiveNumber();

     negativeLink.setNextChain(zeroLink);
     zeroLink.setNextChain(positiveLink);
```

So, I'd like to know, if I understood it properly. Basicly, this method will chain up another process class, when the first one (in this case **NegativeNumber**) can't do much here, because let's say that user will enter the number equals to 3. So program will check that if entered number is <0 if it's not, the number will be checked by another process class (**ZeroNumber**) if number is not equal to 0, then another chain will check it (**PositiveNumber**). So am I understand the logic behind it well?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: The problem here is: it seems someone gave you an assignment, and then you somehow implemented something. But how are we supposed to know exactly why/how you did those things, and what they "mean"? It feels like you should rather talk with your peers/tutor/instructors (in that order) to clarify your doubts.

Comment: Yes, I did. You seem to be asking how a one-liner method with single property assignment works. If that's so, I would rather just bounce you to read some tutorial about how the language works in general, as there's no point for me to reiterate what's in that tutorial in an answer on SO.

Comment: @abdig you should google on chain-of-responsibility design pattern and relate it with your question.

Comment: And just for the record: yes, me too: I don't see the "point" of the code you are showing here. I am not sure what it is meant to do, or why it is written that way. In other words: me, too, I dont understand what you are *really* asking us.

Comment: I think perhaps the best thing to do is if you [edit] your question and add some explanation: "I understand that the chain of responsibility concept is supposed to work like this: X, Y, Z, but in this code, I don't see how the Y part is done". This is because we don't know what you understand of the chain-of-responsibility principles, so we don't know what you expect the code to be doing.

Comment: Just edited question. Did I explained the problem well now?

Comment: @abdig, "_am I understand the logic behind it well?_" - yes, pretty much that's what it does. These three chain links cover all the cases in input that you've distinguished. I still don't particularly understand why you had to ask the question here and not just made a simple test and debug the code.